# Syntax to change image source based on states and props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a parent component that contains a child component:

```
return(
  <ChildComponent state={this.getState} />
);
```

Inside m child component:

```
return(
  <Avatar src="./picture" />
);
```

I want to change the source based on the state of the parent. For example if the state of the parent was 1 i the source will be picture1 or if the state was 2 the source would be picture2 and if the state was 3 it would be picture 3. I'm not sure what the syntax would be to complete the child's image source. Would it be something like this:

```
<Avatar src="'./picture' + this.props.state + '.jpg'"/>
```

EDIT: just wanted to make it clear I am using a material UI component called avatar. (changed img to avatar) Documentation: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/avatar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child component should not get the state from the parent, but the *props*:

```
return(
  <ChildComponent number={this.state.number} />
);
```

Then you can use the props to construct a source (notice that the `number` prop is a javascript expression and not a string like in your example):

```
return(
  <Avatar src={"./picture" + this.props.number + ".jpg"} />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case instead of `""` use `{}` like this

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Avatar src={'./picture' + this.props.src + '.jpg'}/>
  }
});

var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { counter: 0 }
  },

  handleNext: function () {
    this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },

  handlePrev: function () {
    this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter - 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div> 
      <ChildComponent src={this.state.counter} />
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleNext}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={this.handlePrev}>Prev</button>
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
});
```